# Spring Data Redis: Connect via UNIX Sockets

Tags: spring, sockets, redis, unix-socket, spring-data-redis

I'm currently researching on Redis to retrieve data via UNIX sockets.

I've updated the redis.conf file to reflect this, by defining the path to redis.sock (in my case it is /tmp/redis.sock).

Using Spring Data Redis (via `JedisConnectionFactory`), I can see that it has methods for connecting to Redis via TCP (i.e. defining hostname and port). However, I don't see there being any methods used for connecting via UNIX sockets (unless I've overlooked something).

Does anyone know how I can connect to Redis using UNIX sockets via Spring Data Redis?

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> Java cannot create or access Unix Domain Sockets without using a 3rd party (native) library.

That's correct in general. Jedis has (as of writing this answer) no Unix Domain Socket support. [Lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core) and [Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) use netty for I/O which has support for [native transports](http://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html) (epoll and kqueue). A native transport is required to use Unix Domain Sockets which depends on the underlying operating system.

Lettuce is integrated into [Spring Data Redis](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:connectors:lettuce) but there's no native transport option [yet](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-682).

References:

- [Jedis #492 Support Unix Domain Sockets](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/492)
- [Lettuce: Reference documentation on Unix Domain Sockets](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Unix-Domain-Sockets)
- [Redisson: Configuration of Unix Domain Sockets](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#uselinuxnativeepoll)

Comment: I filed a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-682) to support unix domain socket connections.

Comment: As of today, Redisson still does not support it: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/773

Answer (score 1):

Java cannot create or access Unix Domain Sockets without using a 3rd party (native) library.

And the spring-data-redis use the Jedis or Jredis or others as engine. Jedis does not support this method to connect. I think others do not support it also. Because the unix socket can only be used in local machine.

You can check this client library to make sure this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround with `socat`.  This is what I did for my DockerSwarmDiscoveryClient which required access to the `/var/run/docker.sock` but I only had the Spring WebClient which only supports TCP connections.

In a Docker context you can set up

```
  daemon:
    image: alpine/socat
    command: tcp-listen:2375,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```